# Assign class to link_to using html slim

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, slim-lang

I'm working on a html slim file for a Ruby on Rails project. I want to create a button of class `btn btn-primary` (I'm using bootstrap) for a controller action. Name of controller is default_responses and action is edit. So I first did:

```
= link_to 'Test this', :controller => 'default_responses', :action => 'edit', :id => params[:id].to_i
```

This would become

```
<a href="/default_responses/7/edit">Test this</a>
```

where 7 is the id parameter and is correct for my case. However, it is not a button at all, just an anchored tag. It also redirects me to the correct page.

Then I tried

```
 = link_to 'Test this', :controller => 'default_responses', :action => 'edit', :id => params[:id].to_i, class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

which gave me

```
<a href="/default_responses/7/edit?class=btn+btn-primary">Test this</a>
```

This is still not what I want as it is not a button still.

Also tried `= link_to 'Test this', :controller => 'default_responses', :action => 'edit', :id => params[:id].to_i, :class=> 'btn btn-primary'`

It returned `<a href="/default_responses/7/edit?class=btn+btn-primary">Test this</a>` which is still wrong.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Add the classes `btn btn-primary` to the class of the anchor as per https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/

Comment: `<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link</a>`
`<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Button</button>`
`<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Input">`

Are all valid ways to create buttons in Bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

Rails' [`link_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) takes multiple hash options, in your example you're supplying a single hash option, which all get passed into the `url_options` section. You'll need to add the curly brackets (`{}`) around the first hash to tell ruby which option goes to which hash.

```
= link_to 'Test this', { :controller => 'default_responses', :action => 'edit', :id => params[:id].to_i }, class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

should work. Of course, you could also use a url helper (`url_for`, `default_responses_path`, etc) instead of the first hash.